# using map or similar to update a dictionary when not using a class

Tags: python, function, dictionary, functional-programming

When one is not using methods, what is the best, way to achieve the following.

1. have a single function for adding items to a dictionary
2. use that function when adding multiple items to the dictionary
3. Does this make everything super slow?

The following works, I am not very serious about using it, but am interested in what is possible.

Simple functions to create, and update a dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial

def addfoo(mydict, foo):
    x,y,z = foo
    mydict[x].add((y,z))
    mydict[y].add((x,z))
    return mydict

makemydict = partial(addfoo, defaultdict(set))

foo = ('foo','bar',1)

mydict = makemydict(foo)

print(mydict)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'foo': {('bar', 1)}, 'bar': {('foo', 1)}})
```

While the next part of this works, I was wondering if there was a way to use map, to run the function over the 'foos' (plural). but as the addfoo function returns a value, how could that be mapped over. The following works, but are there any other ways?

```
def addfoos(mydict, foos):
    for foo in foos:
        mydict = addfoo(mydict,foo)
    return mydict

makemany = partial(addfoos, defaultdict(set))

foos = { ('foo','bar',1),
         ('bar','baz',0) }

mydict = makemany(foos)

print(mydict)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'baz': {('bar', 0)}, 'foo': {('bar', 1)}, 'bar': {('foo', 1), ('baz', 0)}})
```

As it is, it works... but I am curious if python has a fmap or similar.

---

OK... for anyone stumbling across this -- use reduce!

the following, although with different variables is exactly what I was aiming for:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
from functools import reduce

def addnode(graph, node):
    x,y,z = node
    graph[x].add((y,z))
    graph[y].add((x,z))
    return graph

def addnodes(graph, nodes):
    return reduce(addnode, nodes, graph)

graphnode  = partial(addnode, defaultdict(set))
graphnodes = partial(addnodes, defaultdict(set))
```

and now, either function (`addnode` or `addnodes`) can be called to update the dict.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but isn't it fold/reduce you are after, rather than map?

Comment: quite possibly... it would make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `reduce`, not `map`, since you're reducing the inputs to a single result, rather than transforming them one-to-one to a list of results.

```
>>> reduce(addfoo, foos, defaultdict(set))
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'baz': set([('bar', 0)]), 'foo': set([('bar', 1)]), 'bar': set([('foo', 1), ('baz', 0)])})
```

That was python 2.6.  Python3 version works the same, but `reduce` is in `functools` now:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(addfoo, foos, defaultdict(set))
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'baz': {('bar', 0)}, 'foo': {('bar', 1)}, 'bar': {('foo', 1), ('baz', 0)}})
```

Comment: so when using reduce, and arguments that the function takes are appended to the end? P.S, the amount of times I have been messing around with extra lambda functions when using reduce is not funny...

Comment: Yes, `reduce(function,sequence,initial)` basically does something like this: `curr=initial; for item in sequence: curr = function(curr,item)` - I hope that makes sense.  And I know, my first attempt at this involved unnecessary lambda functions too... ;)

Comment: yep, that does indeed. Brilliant. I love it when things suddenly get a whole lot easier :)

Comment: Yeah, `reduce` is such a fun simplifying thing to do sometimes. :)